# Java Class to convert a string returns empty

Tags: java, string

Class to convert a string returns empty:

Hello! I am creating a class with a method to invert a String (by the way, I have already done this many times, only not as a class and instantiated in an object) The program compiles and does not show an error, it only returns the empty string and does not take the reversed string value.

```java
    public class InvertString {
        //Attribute
        public String invertedString = "";
        //Method
        public String mInvertString(String text) {
            
            for (int i = text.length()-1; i <= 0; i--) {
                invertedString += text.charAt(i);
            }
            
            return invertedString;
        }
    }
    
    
    public class MainInvertString {
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            InvertString invertString = new InvertString();
            String test = invertString.mInvertString("Hello");
            System.out.println("Result: "+test);
    
        }
    
    }
```

Comment: Can you elaborate where are you writing and compiling it and also give a snippet for the output. I don't think this is how class works. The `class InvertString` needs to be in a separate file. Also `i<=0` is not correct it should be `i>=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is here:

```
i <= 0
```

It should be `i >= 0`.

But simpler would be to use: `new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString()`